# Loading data from dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Load other two DataFrames: g1900s, and g2000s. These contain the Gapminder life expectancy data for, respectively, the 19th century, the 20th century (1900-1999, starts from 263 row in gapminder.csv), and the 21st (2000-2016, starts from 523 row) century and 'Life expectancy' (as first column) each.

```
gapminder = pd.read_csv('gapminder.csv', index_col=0)
cols_g1900s = ['Life expectancy'] + list(gapminder.loc[:,'1900':'1999'])
g1900s = gapminder.loc[:, cols_g1900s]
print(g1900s.head())
```

That's code which I have for now shows everything like it should, the only thing that it shows only nan values.

DataFrame:

[image: DATAFRAME]

My bad result:

[image: MY BAD RESULT]

What I need:

[image: WHAT I NEED]

Probably I need to select ranges somehow but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.columns`:

```py
gapminder = pd.read_csv('gapminder.csv', index_col=0)
cols_g1900s = ['Life expectancy'] + list(gapminder.loc[:,'1900':'1999'].columns)
g1900s = gapminder.loc[:, cols_g1900s]
print(g1900s.head())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to filter all the 19th century and then `df.columns`

```py
cols_g1900s = ['Life expectancy'] + gapminderdf.filter(regex='^19').columns.tolist()
g1900s = gapminder[cols_g1900s]
```